# Where can I find additional resources about Wildlands Provincial parks in Alberta?

Tags: hiking, camping, backcountry, canada

I'm planning an overnight hiking trip in Alberta, it will involve one night of camping. I know that in Alberta you are allowed to "random camp" in [Wildland Provincial parks](http://www.albertaparks.ca/albertaparksca/library/land-reference-manual/parks-by-class.aspx?id=Wildland%20Provincial%20Park), so I'll be heading to one of those.

The problem is that besides the difficult to read overview maps provided in the previous link I can't seem to find any other info about these parks.

Specifically I was looking for a province map that shows all these parks, and parking lots that are available so I can plan my trip accordingly. Is there any info available, provided by others who have done hiking and random camping in the province?

Answer (score 4):

[AlbertaParks.ca](http://www.albertaparks.ca/whitehorse.aspx) is *the* resource about all parks in Alberta. I find the [maps](http://www.albertaparks.ca/media/5517941/whitehorse-wpp-map.pdf) perfectly easy to read myself. If you want to see where all the parks are, just use [google maps](https://www.google.ca/maps/place/Whitehorse+Wildland,+Yellowhead+County,+AB+T0E/@52.9560555,-117.3478255,11z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m2!3m1!1s0x539d1e592c1201f9:0x10457329e7bfd71e), it highlights all provincial, National, and even some regional parks in green, and shows you all roads.

[image]

Comment: Hmm, that link you posted is readable, but I saw several like this one before: http://www.albertaparks.ca/media/2941/365.PDF

Comment: Google maps is definitely useful, I just have to keep in mind that for low use locations it might be out of date. At least one of the parks Google couldn't give me road directions to. Something like [this site](http://www.everytrail.com/browse.php?activity_id=28&country=canada&state=Alberta) would be ideal if it were for wildland parks.

Comment: That's a legal boundary map, it's meant for legal purposes, guess they don't have anything else. I've been there though, that happens to be the closest Wildland to where I'm living. If you plan on visiting that area, bring a LOT of heavy duty tent pegs, 100km/h wind gusts are normal there. They have signs to notify truckers about the current windspeeds for the highway that goes past that park, Everyone I know has seen semi trucks upside down in the ditch on that highway, blown right off the road. I even saw a downed airplane driving that way once.

Comment: I have a kinda cool story about that area actually, I met a guy who owns 10,000 acres by Bob Creek who said a USA fighter jet crashed on his land there once, but the government swept in and cleaned the crash up all hush, hush. He wasn't allowed anywhere near it, and he *owned* the land.

Comment: That story is very interesting! How long ago was that?